# Restrict function to maximum 100 executions per minute

Tags: php, sql, time

I have a script that makes multiple POST requests to an API. Rough outline of the script is as follows:

```
define("MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE", 100);

function apirequest ($data) {
    // post data using cURL
}

while ($data = getdata ()) {
    apirequest($data);
}
```

The API is throttled, it allows users to post up to 100 requests per minute. Additional requests return HTTP error + Retry-After response until *the window resets*. Note that the server can take anywhere between 100 milliseconds to 100 seconds to process the request.

I need to make sure that my function does not execute more than 100 times per minute. I have tried `usleep` function to introduce a constant delay of 0.66 seconds but this simply adds one extra minute per minute. An arbitrary value such as 0.1 second results in error one time or another. I log all requests inside a database table along with time, the other solution I used is to probe the table and count the number of requests made within last 60 seconds.

I need a solution that wastes as little time as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put Derek's suggestion into code.

```
class Throttler {
    private $maxRequestsPerMinute;
    private $getdata;
    private $apirequest;

    private $firstRequestTime = null;
    private $requestCount = 0;

    public function __construct(
        int $maxRequestsPerMinute,
        $getdata,
        $apirequest
    ) {
        $this->maxRequestsPerMinute = $maxRequestsPerMinute;
        $this->getdata = $getdata;
        $this->apirequest = $apirequest;
    }

    public function run() {
        while ($data = call_user_func($this->getdata)) {
            if ($this->requestCount >= $this->maxRequestsPerMinute) {
                sleep(ceil($this->firstRequestTime + 60 - microtime(true)));
                $this->firstRequestTime = null;
                $this->requestCount = 0;
            }
            if ($this->firstRequestTime === null) {
                $this->firstRequestTime = microtime(true);
            }
            ++$this->requestCount;
            call_user_func($this->apirequest, $data);
        }
    }
}

$throttler = new Throttler(100, 'getdata', 'apirequest');
$throttler->run();
```

**UPD.** I've put its updated version on Packagist so you can use it with Composer: https://packagist.org/packages/ob-ivan/throttler

To install:

```
composer require ob-ivan/throttler
```

To use:

```
use Ob_Ivan\Throttler\JobInterface;
use Ob_Ivan\Throttler\Throttler;

class SalmanJob implements JobInterface {
    private $data;
    public function next(): bool {
        $this->data = getdata();
        return (bool)$this->data;
    }
    public function execute() {
        apirequest($this->data);
    }
}

$throttler = new Throttler(100, 60);
$throttler->run(new SalmanJob());
```

Please note there are other packages providing the same functionality (I haven't tested any of them):

- https://packagist.org/packages/franzip/throttler
- https://packagist.org/packages/andrey-mashukov/throttler
- https://packagist.org/packages/queryyetsimple/throttler

Comment: I'm looking at it. But don't you need to reset the first request time after sleep?

Comment: Haha, right, I even forgot to set an initial value. Fixed now. The functionality seems interesting, I think I'll put it on composer shortly.

Comment: @SalmanA Please see my edit, it can now be used with composer. And have a look at other packages as well. Do you have your problem solved?

Comment: I have not used the code (turns out that the API's one minute is longer than one minute!) but I am accepting it. PS: I think the counter need to reset every minute as well.

Comment: @SalmanA Thank you, I'll work on improving it. You mentioned using DB to store request times. Does it imply the requests are made from separates script runs? I somehow assumed a long-running script from CLI. Did I guess wrong?

Comment: yes it is a CLI script that makes ~300 GET/PUT/POST/DELETE requests. DB was used to store request/response for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by recording initial time when first request is to be made and then count how many requests are being made. Once 60 requests have been made make sure the current time is at least 1 minute after initial time. If not usleep for however long is left until minute is reached. When minute is reached reset count and initial time value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my go at this:

```
define("MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE", 100);

function apirequest() {
    static $startingTime;
    static $requestCount;
    if ($startingTime === null) {
        $startingTime = time();
    }
    if ($requestCount === null) {
        $requestCount = 0;
    }

    $consumedTime = time() - $startingTime;

    if ($consumedTime >= 60) {
        $startingTime = time();
        $requestCount = 0;
    } elseif ($requestCount === MAX_REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE) {
        sleep(60 - $consumedTime);
        $startingTime = time();
        $requestCount = 0;
    }
    $requestCount++;

    echo sprintf("Request %3d, Range [%d, %d)", $requestCount, $startingTime, $startingTime + 60) . PHP_EOL;
    file_get_contents("http://localhost/apirequest.php");
    // the above script sleeps for 200-400ms
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    apirequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the naive solutions of static sleeps, counting requests, and doing simple math but they tended to be quite inaccurate, unreliable, and generally introduced far more sleeping that was necessary when they could have been doing work. What you want is something that only starts issuing consequential sleeps when you're approaching your rate-limit.

Lifting my solution from a [previous problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335374/93950) for those sweet, sweet internet points:

---

I used some math to figure out a function that would sleep for the correct sum of time over the given request, and allow me to ramp it up exponentially towards the end.

If we express the sleep as:

```
y = e^( (x-A)/B )
```

where `A` and `B` are arbitrary values controlling the shape of the curve, then the sum of all sleeps, `M`, from `0` to `N` requests would be:

```
M = 0∫N e^( (x-A)/B ) dx
```

This is equivalent to:

```
M = B * e^(-A/B) * ( e^(N/B) - 1 )
```

and can be solved with respect to A as:

```
A = B * ln( -1 * (B - B * e^(N/B)) / M )
```

While solving for B would be far more useful, since specifying `A` lets you define a what point the graph ramps up aggressively, the solution to that is mathematically complex, and I've not been able to solve it myself or find anyone *else* that can.

```
/**
 * @param int $period   M, window size in seconds
 * @param int $limit    N, number of requests permitted in the window
 * @param int $used x, current request number
 * @param int $bias B, "bias" value
 */
protected static function ratelimit($period, $limit, $used, $bias=20) {
    $period = $period * pow(10,6);
    $sleep = pow(M_E, ($used - self::biasCoeff($period, $limit, $bias))/$bias);
    usleep($sleep);
}

protected static function biasCoeff($period, $limit, $bias) {
    $key = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $period, $limit, $bias);
    if( ! key_exists($key, self::$_bcache) ) {
        self::$_bcache[$key] = $bias * log( -1 * ( ($bias - $bias * pow(M_E, $limit/$bias)) / $period ) );
    }
    return self::$_bcache[$key];
}
```

With a bit of tinkering I've found that `B = 20` seems to be a decent default, though I have no mathematical basis for it. *Something something* slope *mumble mumble* exponential *bs bs*.

Also, if anyone wants to solve that equation for `B` for me [I've got a bounty up on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989587/formula-for-exponential-backoff-rate-limiting).

---

Though I believe that our situations differ slightly in that my API provider's responses all included the number of available API calls, and the number still remaining within the window. You may need additional code to track this on your side instead.